# Partition/sort keys for querying/comparing date ranges in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I've got a DynamoDB `tickets` table for a basic ticket management/calendar app.

The tickets each store a date range, and I need to query them based on whether they overlap a certain other date range.

For example, there's a scrolling calendar, and as a user scrolls into the past/future, I retrieve the tickets that appear within that visible area's date range. I also look for date conflicts, so I am checking to see whether tickets exist that overlap a certain date range.

Right now, I'm using a unique id for each ticket for the partition key (not using any sort key), using a paginated `scan` to get all the tickets, and checking every one in a lambda to see if date ranges overlap (`ticket.start < range.end && ticket.end > range.start`).

What I'm doing feels very inefficient, and I'm already running into some `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException` errors with light usage even though the table is set to auto-scale.

Is there a better way in DynamoDB to handle this (perhaps a smart usage of the partition/sort keys)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there's a much better approach. Assuming you have a common denominator for tickets, such as tickets for a given users calendar or for a certain company, that `id` would be best served as partition key. The sort key would be a timestamp.

That will allow you to easily get tickets for a given users between two dates, efficiently.

If you don't have a common denominator and you want to show all tickets that exist in the table, then consider using a single value as partition key. This blog will help:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/effective-data-sorting-with-amazon-dynamodb/

Comment: The timestamp sort key approach sounds like it'd work if I was storing a single date on each ticket, but my tickets have date ranges.

Comment: For example, how do I make sure a ticket with start date 2023-12-31 and end date 2024-01-01 gets returned whether I'm querying tickets in 2023 or 2024?

Comment: You should only act on a single date and then filter out the remainder using a filter expression. Give me all the tickets with start date between X+Y, then use a filter to filter out the ones who's end date need to meet a criteria.

Comment: I can't check the start date between X&Y because that will not return tickets that start before X but end after X (like the example I commented above). Seems the best I can do is get all the tickets that start before Y?

Comment: Talking through this has helped me find similar questions here that seems to get at the same problem (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71360821/dynamodb-get-all-items-which-overlap-a-search-time-interval)